# Can't see knowledge articles in customer center portal

Tags: customer-community, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I have a customer portal which is built on salesforce tabs + visual force template. We are integrating with coveo to publish the knowledge articles to external customer user. The issue is in coveo global search i can see the the knowledge articles. When I click on one of the article, it is redirecting me to internal salesforce. I want it to be redirected and opened in separate customer center portal only. I checked the profile , knowledge object is enabled. I enebled Knowledge one app permission for permission set for that user. I can see the articles in coveo search and results but not when I use knowledge tab url in the customer center portal i.e. https://knwl.c33.force.com/customercenter/_ui/knowledge/ui/KnowledgeHome. I am a system admin and with my user I can see the articles and when I open it is opening in external customer center only while I am previewing the portal. My requirement is whatever articles I see in the search results, when I open one of them it should redirect me to separate page on customer portal. I am new to knowledge and service cloud. Please suggest me what I should do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that a similar question was asked [here](https://answers.coveo.com/questions/16828/search-results-linking-to-internal-salesforce-know.html) and should solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: thanks will check on it